# I have been using firebase in a terminal . I am getting this error when i go for deploying

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

```
$ firebase deploy
```

> npm ERR! code Z_DATA_ERROR npm ERR! errno -3 npm ERR! invalid distance
>   too far back
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2018-10-16T05_15_44_149Z-debug.log
>
> Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log?

Comment: Please provide the version of npm and Node.js you have installed on your system.

Comment: it has version - 6.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it , just by downgrading my npm version

Comment: I used version 6.4.1